# How to insert option values in select using Prototype JS?

Tags: javascript, prototype

This is my js code:

```
 html = "";
 Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
       html += "<option value='" + obj[key].entity_id + "'>" + obj[key].name + "</option>";
 });
 $('_accountmedical_location').insert({ 'after' : html });
```

I wonder if there is a function from prototype which insert some html code inside an element, like:

```
$('_accountmedical_location').insert({ 'inside' : html });
```

I already have the option html code, I just simply want to put it inside my select. How can I do that ? thx

Comment: @Mr.7 As I said I already have the html part and I want to insert it in my select. The post that  you gave wants set the option value and text value with prototype.

Comment: Okay, Apologies for misunderstanding.

Comment: Do you want to append the **option** elements to **select** elemet? Just use [jQuery.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to append **option** element to it.

Comment: There is no append function in prototype from far as I know . I have to use prototype... :(